# Dashed draw with a node including a fraction

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, rules

Is this intended behavior (with plain XeTeX):

```
\input tikz
\tikz\draw[dashed] node {$3T\over4$};
\bye
```

It renders as: [image]!?

The fraction line is dashed, too! Is this intentional? Is there something I can do to change that? I know I can separate the fraction into its own node, but other than that?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run the file through TeX and view the DVI it's just a regular line, same when I then convert it to pdf and view that.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker: A-ha! It doesn't happen with pdftex, but with xetex.

Comment: Status no repo.  Tried with LaTeX running pdflatex, tried also with tex on the commandline with your exact code.  Both times, I get a good solid line across.  Could it be a version issue?

Comment: Okay, I get it with xe(la)tex.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, RoelofSpijker: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: With `\tikz\draw[dashed] node {\vrule height 1pt width 1cm};` the rule is dashed with XeTeX, but not with (pdf)TeX. It's a driver bug/feature.

Comment: [Fixed in CVS.](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/136/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a guess, what's happening is that the `dashed` is getting applied to a low-level scope which includes the horizontal line from the fraction.  So, without knowing the gory details, there's some conversation something like:

- *TeX*: Okay, we're drawing dashed lines here
- *PDF*: Right, setting lines to *dashed*
- *TeX*: Now, we need to draw a fraction
- *PDF*: A *what*?
- *TeX*: I mean, draw a `3T` a little high, a `4` a little low, and draw a line in between
- *PDF*: Gotcha, oh and I presume that the "dashed" still applies to the line

Presumably in other systems, the method for drawing the lines from PGF and the lines from other stuff don't end up mixed like that.

A proper solution would involve sorting out the scoping so that the `dashed` doesn't apply to the line.  A hack is to negate the `dashed` when processing the node.  Being me, I'm going for the hack:

```
\input tikz
\tikz\draw[dashed] node[solid] {$3T\over4$};
\bye
```

Comment: Andrew, I'm very happy with this solution, thank you very much!