# How to get proper kerning with XeTeX and special characters?

Tags: xetex, characters, kerning

I would love to switch to XeTeX to make use of my professional Adobe fonts that were shipped with Creative Suite 6.

I use MikTeX on a Win 8 machine, and TeXniXcenter + XeTeX.

However, kerning seems to an issue, especially with special characters, in my case *German Umlaute*.

Spacing seems wrong, at least for characters `W`+`ü`. Actually, on a sidenote, I don't understand why `--` does not give me a long dash...

Here is my MWE (UTF8) and a screenshot showing the wrong kerning:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

Wäre -- Könnte -- Wüste

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add the option `Mapping= tex-text` to the font specification to enable the translation of en- and emdashes. Furthermore, it seems that only some glyphs like `ä` and `à` show this bad kerning, while `á` and (normal) `a` work fine.

Comment: I think it is still this problem: http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-February/019956.html. And http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45460/kerning-issue-with-adobe-garamond-pro-xetex-or-font-file-to-blame

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem! Can get marked as duplicate.

Comment: This should be fixed in the development version of XeTeX already, which (hopefully) will be available in the next TeX Live.