# xelatex myriad pro l with apostrophe issue

Tags: fonts, xetex

I compile my document with xelatex.
I use Myriad pro

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
```

My problem is that the "l'a" is looking OK but not the "l'i" the i touches the apostrophes. Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: The kerning of the apostrophe in Minion Pro and Myriad Pro is known to be bad. `:(`

Comment: in pdfTeX, things like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nJaiFt9A) were possible. Let's hope the `kerning` feature will be back in `microtype` for Xe/LuaLaTeX someday.

Comment: Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45460/kerning-issue-with-adobe-garamond-pro-xetex-or-font-file-to-blame

Comment: It is an ugly solution, but you could manually add kerning... Defining some macros would make it much easier. Alternatively, you could open the font in Fontforge and change the kerning there. It involves some work but it is doable. I am not really sure if it permitted by the fonts license though...

Comment: @all thanks for your your answers. I have another question. Is there any other font very similar to myriad pro that handles better the appostrophes?

Comment: @Swiss12000 – Did you have a look at Frutiger? I can't guarantee good apostrophe kerning, but it's a very similar typeface.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the font, you can find this out by writing the same thing into another program. It is a issue with [ICU engine with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45460/kerning-issue-with-adobe-garamond-pro-xetex-or-font-file-to-blame#comment93256_45460).

One way to fix it is to issue a zero kern after the apostrophe:

```
l'\kern0pt inno
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to insert that kern automatically.
See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45489/1410) on how to do it.

Here's an example as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Myriad Pro}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \aposclass
\XeTeXcharclass `' \aposclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks \aposclass 0 = {\kern0pt }
\begin{document}
L'arbre de l'inno
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah sorry, i did not mean that myriad pro font has issues. I means that xelatex makes issue with myriad pro font... Whatever, your l'\kern0pt  solution works fine. However I don't get how to use \XeTeXinterchartoks in my case. I saw the other topic which is related to other letters issue. So can you tell me how to use \XeTeXinterchartoks for my case? Thanks a lot to you ;)

Comment: @Swiss12000: Sure, updated to include example. If I've understood correctly, the ICU engine will be replaced in TL2013 so this would not be needed then.

Comment: hum good news that they will improve those kind of issue. However, for the moment the code your gave me doesn't give error message when I compile. However the appostrophe + i doesn't change (still sticked togheter...)

Comment: @Swiss12000: That's weird. I even tried with Plain-XeTeX (with explicit "/ICU"-switch) and it works for me. What versions are you running? (I tried with TeXLive2012, Myriad Pro version 2.102, OS X 10.8.3.)

Comment: I have the latest version of miktex 2.9.4813 with windows 7.

Comment: Right, this is a bug in ICU Layout Engine and it was fixed by the switch to HarfBuzz.

Comment: @Swiss12000: I am sorry to tell you but unfortunately I don't have a win7 at my disposal, so I cannot help you further. However, if you could include a MWE (that is, with a `\documentclass` and all) and those version informations inside the original question, then I hope you would get a better chance of getting an answer which works for you.